# Mapping in d3 ordinal scales

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am using D3's ordinal scale, to map numbers to color. 
I have used this:

```js
color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#1f77b4", "#ff7f0e", "#2ca02c", "#d62728", "#9467bd", "#8c564b", "#e377c2"]).domain([0,6]);
console.log(color(0),color(1),color(2),color(3),color(4),color(5),color(6));
```

The response I am getting is:

`#1f77b4 #2ca02c #d62728 #9467bd #8c564b #e377c2 #ff7f0e`

I am curious shouldn't the response be:

`#1f77b4, #ff7f0e, #2ca02c, #d62728, #9467bd, #8c564b, #e377c2`

Please advise.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The domain isn't quite right:

```
> color.domain()
[0, 6, 1, 0.5]
```

For each value in an [ordinal scale's](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales) range, there should to be a matching value in the domain.

Instead of setting the domain to `[0,6]`, it should be `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`:

```
color = d3.scale.ordinal()
          .range(["#1f77b4", "#ff7f0e", "#2ca02c", "#d62728", "#9467bd", "#8c564b", "#e377c2"])
          .domain(d3.range(0,7));
```

Checking to make sure everything works after updating color:

```
> d3.range(0,7).forEach(function(d){ console.log(color(d)); })
#1f77b4
#ff7f0e
#2ca02c
#d62728
#9467bd
#8c564b
#e377c2
```

Comment: Thanks alot!
That really helped alot. Sorry I dont have permission/points to give you a vote up! But once i will get it i will surely give you a up vote.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

This is expected as there are only 2 explicitly defined values in your domain. So the first value of 0 is assigned to the first color of `#1f77b4`, the second value of 6 is assigned to the second color,`#ff7f0e`, and the remainders are inferred after they are sorted internally as strings. You need to define the domain explicitly for predictable behavior. For example,

```
color = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .range(["#1f77b4", "#ff7f0e", "#2ca02c", "#d62728", "#9467bd", "#8c564b", "#e377c2"])
  .domain([0,1,2,3,4,5,6]);

console.log(color(0),color(1),color(2),color(3),color(4),color(5),color(6));
```

As the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#wiki-ordinal_domain)  states

> Setting the domain on an ordinal scale is optional. If no domain is set, each unique value that is passed to the scale function will be assigned a new value from the output range; in other words, the domain will be inferred implicitly from usage. **However, it is a good idea to assign the ordinal scale's domain to ensure deterministic behavior**, as inferring the domain from usage will be dependent on ordering.